# Android Resource linking failed in my project

Tags: android

Hello guy i have problem , when i want to build the project , i got this error code .

This detail error .

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:9: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:17: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:415: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:415: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:415: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\HP\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\cfb1f54b465b475e1d07b4e8c56e68a1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.projects.realestatefinder\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        D:\Zakario\ANDROID\realestatefinde\codecanyon-17451120-realestate-finder-full-android-application\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstate Finder Android v1.7\RealEstateFinder\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

I have the last version of android studio and my project worked perfectly before upgrading my gradle... 
Please your help guys

Comment: try deleting `.gradle` and `build` folders, they are safe to delete

Answer (score 0):

Try to `clean` and `rebuild` your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your compile SDK is 25, while you (or one of your dependencies) is trying to use resources that were added only in API 28. Edit your `build.gradle` file to use the newest compile SDK:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28 // you currently have 25
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is may be because of wrong attributes added to your xml file. Go to your Activity xml file and see. The error will be shown by Android Studio itself. Remove the attributes.